# How to use lambda i=i with event?

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

I'm experimenting with using `lambda event:` and tkinter for the first time and I've run into difficulty when using it in a loop.

I understand I need to specify what `i` equals when using `lambda`, but I'm not sure how to do this in conjunction with `event`. I want the tkinter buttons to match up with keyboard input so they both print their corresponding text, so when I hit `1` on my keyboard the program prints `1` and so on.

```
numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
counter = 0

for x in range(len(numbers)):
    key = Button(w, text=numbers[counter], 
                 command=lambda i=numbers[counter]: do_something(i))

    root.bind(number[counter], lambda event: 
              do_something(numbers[counter]))

    counter += 1

def do_something(event, text):
    print(text)
```

The existing tkinter buttons work great because I have `i=numbers[counter]` after `lambda`, but I'm getting `IndexError: list index out of range` because I don't when I'm binding the `do_something` function.

How can I solve this problem?

**TL;DR**
I want to do something this but I don't know how:

`root.bind(test[counter], lambda event: i=numbers[counter]: self.keyboard_input(numbers[counter]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same idea, you’re creating an optional parameter with a default value:

```
lambda event, i=numbers[counter]: do_something(i)
```

(although `i` is a bit of a strange name choice.)

Consider calling a function instead so there’s no need to repeat this hack, and looping over the items of the list directly if you don’t use the counter outside of as an index:

```
def create_button(number):
    key = Button(w, text=number,
                 command=lambda: do_something(number))

    root.bind(number, lambda event: do_something(number))


numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

for number in numbers:
    create_button(number)
```

Comment: I've never face palmed this hard before now. Thank you so much for your answer, I can't believe I was so close!